# Find key from array of objects the includes a key word - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
 [
  {
    Other: 23,
  },
  {
    Choco: 21,
  },
  {
    Vanila: 10,
  },
  {
    "Other - WA": 2,
  },
  {
    Strawbery: 30,
  },
];
```

What needs to be done is I have to sort this by showing :

1. All that have keys 'Other'.
2. The rest starting from most to least by value.

I figured I could create 2 separate arrays by moving all that have key 'Other' there and the rest in a separate one. Then I simply sort by value and then join the 2 arrays using spread operator. The problem is I can't get it to detect 'Other' in the key and when it does it does it literally not like how 'LIKE' from SQL would do here's the code for now:

```
let other = pgData.contents[6]?.locCounts?.filter((loc) =>
  Object.keys(loc).includes("Other")
);
```

It only returns key with "Other" not "Other - WA" like I want to get everything that has the word "Other" in it regardless of whats in front of it.

Comment: The root of the problem is the key isn't in a terribly useful/consistent format, leading to this rather nasty situation of having to call `Object.keys` just to figure out the name, and prohibiting other properties from being added. I recommend a structure like `{name: "Other", price: 23}` or something like that, then you'll find it much less awkward to work with going forward.

Comment: I know but the backend is being made by someone else :(. That's why I prefer full stack but this is the pickel I'm in right now.

Comment: Yes, you can perform a one-off, up-front normalization procedure, then it's smooth sailing. The problem with the given answers is that even after sorting, the structure is still fundamentally awkward to work with and you'll still need to call `Object.keys(el)[0]`/`Object.values(el)[0]` every time you use the array when you could be doing the much more intuitive `el.name`/`el.price` (or whatever the k/v pair represents--hard to know under the current format).

Comment: Searching the keys is unnecessary since the data structure already shows you have one element in each key array. Simply `[0]` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes()` on an iterator does an exact match against the elements, not a substring match. Use `find()` with a callback function that performs a substring match. You can use `includes` on the key to check for a substring there.

```
Object.keys(loc).find(key => key.includes("Other"))
```

If you want to make two arrays, you can do it in a single loop instead of using two calls `filter()`:

```
let other = [];
let not_other = [];
pgData.contents[6]?.locCounts?.forEach(loc => {
  if (Object.keys(loc).find(key => key.includes("Other"))) {
    other.push(loc);
  } else {
    not_other.push(loc);
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes()` does, `String.prototype.includes()` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I simply modified your code a bit. Here's a one-liner:

```js
var arr = [{
    Other: 23,
  },
  {
    Choco: 21,
  },
  {
    Vanila: 10,
  },
  {
    "Other - WA": 2,
  },
  {
    Strawbery: 30,
  },
]

var newArr = arr.filter(el => Object.keys(el)[0].includes("Other"))

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could iterate the items and use include on the values like this:

```js
let arrayOfObj = [
  {
    Other: 23,
  },
  {
    Choco: 21,
  },
  {
    Vanila: 10,
  },
  {
    "Other - WA": 2,
  },
  {
    Strawbery: 30,
  },
];

let results = []

arrayOfObj.forEach( (e)=> {
  keys = Object.keys(e)
  others = keys.forEach(
  (e)=> {
    if (e.includes('Other')) {
      results.push(e)
    }
  })
})

console.log(results)
```